# Как отследить события с динамического контента?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ajax, javascript

Имеем автокомплит по названию предприятия

```
$("#firms").autocomplete({
    source: "ajax_firms.cgi",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_staff.cgi",
            data: "firms=" + (ui.item.id),
            success: function (html) {
                $("#value").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

При успешном выборе нами генерируется динамическая форма с именами сотрудников

```
<select name="person" id="person">
    <option value="1">person1</option>
    <option value="2">person2</option>
</select>
```

Как отследить событие при смене сотрудника? Пробовал .change, но оно динамические ловить не хочет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как сказано, селект генерируется динамически. Это означает, что обработчик на него нужно вешать только после того, как он добавлен на страницу или с помощью [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). 
Либо выводить по умолчанию пустой скрытый селект, а после выбора фирмы заполнять его и отображать на странице

Comment: Ну да что-то типа:

    $("#value select").live("change", function () {...});

Comment: С момента ответа произошли изменения в jQuery: Метод `live()` помечен устаревшим в версии 1.7 и удален в версии 1.9

Answer (score 3):

спасибо.
так вышло еще оптимальней

```
$("#persons").on("change","#person", function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

> пробовал .change, но оно динамические ловить не хочет.

Вы ошибаетесь.

```
<select name="person" id="person" onchange="alert(this.value);">
    <option value="1">person1</option>
    <option value="2">person2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Expert скосячил, да.

Comment: я пробовал вот так, ловить не хочет

    $("select").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        $("div").text(str);
    })
    .trigger('change');

мне для обработки надо еще выводить дополнительно данные о сотруднике, как выбранногопо умолчанию, так и измененного.
к сожалению не могу получить ни того ни того.